# google maps directions service not showing route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used the simple directions service api sample provided by google maps api, while the map does seem to adjust to show the two different points, there is no route or markers plotted.

[directions-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Here is what I have:

```
var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;    

function initialize(data) {
          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom:7,
            center: chicago
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        }

        function calcRoute() {
          var start = "chicago, il";
          var end = "st louis, mo";
          var request = {
              origin:start,
              destination:end,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          });
        }


<div style="height: 25rem; width: 40rem;" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

What am I missing in my code to display default markers and route line?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you calling the `calcRoute` function somehow? [when I call that inside the `initialize` function, it works](http://jsfiddle.net/w4tzk13c/)

Comment: @geocodezip I do have a html button that calls calcRoute(), it cause a reaction to the map, but markers and polyline are missing.

Comment: I don't see that in your question. The fiddle in my comment works (it contains the code posted, but calls `calcRoute()` in `initialize`).  You have a problem that isn't in the information you provided.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are asking about.

Answer (score -1):

you must call calcRoute() somewhere after initialization.. you can do this at the end of initialization(); example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }

        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: chicago
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            calcRoute();
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = "chicago, il";
            var end = "st louis, mo";
            var request = {
                origin:start,
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well obviously html you pointed out is strictly for changing the start and end values. The css does not do anything for the route either just sets map boundries and how the drop down select box will look.

Comment: I changed my answer, you can see it above